# Generate backup script of SQL Agent Jobs using c#

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scripting, jobs

I am using C# code to read all the SQL Agent Jobs:

```cs
static readonly string SqlAgentJobName = "SqlAgentJob_123";
static ServerConnection conn;
static Server server;
static Job job;

try
{
    conn = new ServerConnection(SqlServer); 
    server = new Server(conn); 
    job = server.JobServer.Jobs[SqlAgentJobName]; //Get the specified job
    GenerateScript(job); // I need idea to write this method.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to fetch the job :" + ex.Message);
    throw ex;
}
```

How can I generate a script out of it, so that I can run it on any server?
When I run the program, it should read all jobs from the server and generate a script.

Is there any built-in method? Will SQL Server Development Tools help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Script method of the Scripter object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.script.aspx) in SMO to achieve that.

An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488666/how-to-automate-script-generation-using-smo-in-sql-server).